# Java SSL Safety

Tags: java, security, ssl

I have a client-server model that uses SSL on every connection. I have used Java and the common libraries to program this. I have two questions regarding the SSL safety:

1) **Is it considered safe to send the password in plaintext from the client to the server?** The server uses BCrypt to hash the password and store it. I have considered sending an unsalted hash of the password or a nounced hash of the password, but are they truly more safe than sending password in plaintext? I doubt it. I don't think sending the password as a salted hash is a viable option, as the salt would need to be stored somewhere in the client or send over the network, and thus I don't think it would make it inherently more safe as sending the password as plaintext. Due to SSL nobody else should be able to read it anyway, right?

2) **Does encrypted data on SSL always gets encrypted to a different string, and if so, can you use an earlier encryption of a certain string to get the same result later?** To clarify:

- If you encrypt data now, and a few seconds later, does it procide the same cipher text?
- If you use the cipher text from encrypting "test", can you send the same cipher text on a later moment to let the server believe that the client legitly sent "test"?

Under all circumstances the assumption should be made that I do not want to approach this from my own (client or server) perspective, but I want to approach this from a hacker/cheater's point of view.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll answer this another way. SSL has privacy, integrity, and authentication.

1. Privacy: no-one can read the traffic.
2. Integrity: no-one can modify, inject, replay, or truncate the traffic without detection.
3. Authentication: at least one of the peers is reliably authenticated to the other.

(1) disposes of your first question.
(2) disposes of your second question.